# Output several counts of one table records in one row

Tags: sql, count, average, informix, sql-null

Here is an example table CALLRECORD:

```
    +--------+------------+
    |callid  |   rating   |
    |1       |            |
    |2       |   5        |
    |3       |            |
    |4       |   1        |
    |5       |            |
    +--------+------------+
```

No problem to output total number of calls, number of rated calls, average rating and number of unrated calls:

```
select count(*) as total from callrecord;
select count(*) as rated, avg(rating) as average_rating from callrecord where rating is not null;
select count(*) as unrated from callrecord where rating is null;
```

```
    +--------+
    |total   |
    |5       |
    +--------+

    +--------+------------+
    |rated   |average     |
    |2       |3           |
    +--------+------------+

    +--------+
    |unrated |
    |3       |
    +--------+
```

I'm looking for how to output all above to one row with single SQL request:

```
    +--------+--------+------------+---------+
    |total   |rated   |average     |unrated  |
    |5       |2       |3           |3        |
    +--------+--------+------------+---------|
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7522e859e00071275cad6996c7b6c9e)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most aggregate functions ignore `null` values, so what you want is simpler that you may think:

```
select 
    count(*) total,                  -- total number of rows
    count(rating) as rated,          -- count of non-null ratings
    avg(rating) average,             -- avg ignore `null`
    count(*) - count(rating) unrated -- count of null ratings
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SUM aggregation with a CASE statement inside of it. Example below.

```
 Select 
        COUNT(*) AS 'Total', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS 'Rated',
        (SUM(CASE WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE rating END)/SUM(CASE WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) AS 'Avg',
        SUM(CASE WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Unrated'
 From callrecord
```